# I've downloaded an .exe file but it closes quickly as it opens

Tags: exe

I am trying to open a downloaded .exe file but it closes as soon as it opens. Is there any possible way so that I can open it for a longer duration to read the content.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's probably a console application rather than a GUI application.  Use the command prompt to run the .exe.
Do the following...

Hold down your Windows key on your keyboard and then tap "R".
This will bring up the Run dialog.  Type in "cmd" (without the quotes).  Hit enter.
(this will work in all Windows versions - browsing the start menu/screen differs in each version)

If you saved the file to c:\downloads and it's called myFile.exe, type

```
C:
cd C:\Downloads
myFile.exe
```

Some of the steps are a bit redundant - if you know what you're doing in the command prompt then skip as needed (but then you probably wouldn't be posting this question).  This will work even if you saved the file to D:\downloads.

Another example - if you saved the file to D:\folderA\Folder with a space\ and the file is called "my file with a space.exe" then type

```
D:
cd "D:\folderA\Folder with a space"
"my file with a space.exe"
```

If there is an issue (eg it's a 64-bit executable and you're on 32-bit Windows) then you may get a better error message at the command line.

Comment: The file was still not opening but then I used .NET Reflector to get the code and ran that code in visual studio to get the content by adding print commands.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons why the executable does not run. Here are some ways to check what is going wrong:

- Is it your .exe? Do you known the "normal" behavior?
- When you download it manually, it the result the same?
- Do you download the .exe manually or via your application?
- Do you see any problem in your Windows Event Viewer?
- Is it the same result if you try to download the .exe via different browsers (IE, FF, ...)?

More details are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The nuget.exe file is not a console GUI application but rather a console package. Once you've downloaded it, you'll want to place it in a folder outside your Downloads folder. For example, C:\NuGet\nuget.exe - then set it as a PATH variable so that it's executable from anywhere.